# Spherical space form conjecture

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

The spherical space form conjecture (now theorem) asserts that every finite group *acting* on the 3-sphere is conjugate to a subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$. Is the action assumed to be smooth? Can anything similar be said for topological actions? Also, I would appreciate a reference about the spherical space form conjecture.

Comment: I think it's been known for a while (long before Hamilton–Perelman and even Thurston) that in dimension 3 the smooth and topological Poincaré conjectures are equivalent. Unfortunately I don't even seen this mentioned in [Wikipedia's Poincaré conjecture page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture). Hopefully somebody will provide a reference and more precise statement.

Comment: The SFS conjecture is about free finite group actions. If you drop the freeness  assumption then in the smooth category every finite group action is still conjugate to an orthogonal action, but in the topological category this is no longer true (Bing's examples).It is a rather old theorem (Moise+Munkres) that in dimension 3 TOP=DIFF: every topological manifold admits a smooth structure and  this structure is unique up to diffeomorphism. See the references I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606020/classification-of-surfaces-using-point-set-topology/3608795#3608795).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you. Does that mean that the spherical space form conjecture holds for topological, non-smooth actions over S^3 as well?

Comment: No. To rephrase Moishe: If your action is *free*, then it is topologically conjugate to a linear action (smoothly conjugate if the action was smooth to begin with). Non-free topological actions need not be smoothable. Eg, the double of the (non-manifold) Alexander horned ball is homeomorphic to $S^3$, and hence $S^3$ carries an involution with non-locally-flat fixed set, so this action is not even topologically conjugate to a smooth action.

Comment: I wonder if every locally linear (not necessarily free) action of a finite group on $S^3$ is conjugate to a linear action. The Ricci flow proof seems to fail in locally linear setting.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Yes, one can prove that topological 3d orbifolds are smoothable. I am not sure if this is in the literature though. But it should be a good separate question.

Comment: @GeorgeK: Do you understand that your question is based on a false premise?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan I do. I hoped that the fact that the topological and the smooth category coincide in 3 dimensions might yield something good, so I thought to ask. Meanwhile, I found a few papers on the matter and I see that this is not the case. You only have that smooth actions are smoothly conjugate to subgroups of O(4) and that locally linear actions are topologically conjugate to subgroups of O(4) (and O(4) of course further reduces to SO(4) for actions which preserve orientation). At least these are the only results that I found. Thank you all again.